# When my ball hits the ground this function should activate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game where your player should keep the ball in the air and if it hits the ground you lose.
this only seems to work with `OnCollisionEnter` but not with the wanted `OnTriggerEnter`
I'm not getting any error messages just warnings about some bool not being used.
Here my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float upForce = 200f;
    private bool isDead = false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float speed = 2f;
    public static GameControl instance;
    public Text scoreText;
    public GameObject gameOvertext;
    private int score = 0;
    public bool gameOver = false;
    public float scrollSpeed = -1.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision2D other)
    {
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            isDead = true;
            GameControl.instance.YouDied();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your collider a trigger ? (ie. IsTrigger checked ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `OnTriggerEnter()` is wrong, it's:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //
}
```

And since by the looks of it you are working with 2D, it should be:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    //
}
```

Make sure that the `GameObject` containing the script and the `RigidBody2D` or it's children also contains a `Collider2D` with the `IsTrigger` checkbox checked.

Comment: I wouldn't use the last .. it is possible that colliders are somewhere nested under the Rigidbody .. now your script forces you to always have one also on the rigidbody/this gameobject itself

Comment: @derHugo You are right, I was under the impression that the collider had to exist on the same level as the script containing the `OnTriggerEnter()` method.